# How can I update ObservableCollection by its ID using C#?

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0, lambda, observablecollection

I have an **ObservableCollection<>** of custom objects like this

```
public class Employee()
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public decimal salary { get; set; }
}

ObservableCollection<Employee> employeeCollection = new ObservableCollection<Employee>()
{
    new Employee() { id = 1, salary = 1000.00 },
    new Employee() { id = 2, salary = 1500.00 },
    new Employee() { id = 3, salary = 2000.00 },
    new Employee() { id = 4, salary = 2500.00 },
    new Employee() { id = 5, salary = 3000.00 }
};
```

id is the unique property in this collection. How can I update the collection's salary based on id and get the entire collection in the most efficient way?

i.e: If I update the salary to 5000.00 of the employee whose id is 3, the result need to be like this

```
employeeCollection = new ObservableCollection<Employee>()
{
    new Employee() { id = 1, salary = 1000.00 },
    new Employee() { id = 2, salary = 1500.00 },
    new Employee() { id = 3, salary = 5000.00 },
    new Employee() { id = 4, salary = 2500.00 },
    new Employee() { id = 5, salary = 3000.00 }
}
```

I need to get the entire collection with the updated values.

Comment: If you know that an employee with the required id is already in the collection, then you can simply do (using Linq) `employeeCollection.Where(e => e.id == requiredID).First().salary = newSalary;` If it is not certain that an employee with the required id exists you probably have to break this up in two steps (1. checking and finding the employee. 2a. If found, set salary. 2b. If not found, handle the situation according to your needs...)

Comment: @elgonzo No need for the `Where` statement, just move the selection criteria into the `First(...)`

Comment: @MikeH, you are right. Didn't remember that `First` also accepts a predicate. Intellisense rots my brain ;-)

Answer (score 2):

```
var emp = employeeCollection.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == 3)
if(emp != null) // might not exist
   emp.salary = 5000
```

---

If you need to work with a set of records

```
var results = employeeCollection.Where(x => x.Id == 3)

foreach(var emp in results)
   emp.salary = 5000
```

or

```
employeeCollection.Where(x => x.Id == 3)
                  .ToList()
                  .ForEach(x => x.salary = 5000);
```

*Personally i don't like the second approac*h

---

**Additional Resources**

[Enumerable.FirstOrDefault Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> Returns the first element of a sequence, or a default value if no element is found.

Comment: The OP indicates that ID is unique...perhaps a `FirstOrDefault` with a null check?

Comment: Thank you @TheGeneral you saved my life